# Is it invalid/confusing to have the document <header> in the middle of a document

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

I currently have a setup like this:

```
<section id="intro"></section>
<header></header>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

The header element is a sticky header with site name and basic information. It doesn't show until after the user scrolls past #intro, hence where it is in the DOM. I was wondering if, from the point of view of semantics and accessibility, it made more sense to just make it a div or a section.

Comment: Here is a good read: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-future-of-the-web-my-vision-may-1-2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<header>` tag is [not required to be at a specific position in your document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html), except that it should not be a child of another `<header>`, a `<footer>` or an `<address>` tag. The `<div>` element, on the other hand, is [strongly suggested as a last-resort element only](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-div-element.html), to be avoided when another element would fit better semantically. It seems your usage of `<header>` is fits well with its recommended usage, though you should keep in mind that IE8 and earlier versions do not support it and it is effectively unstylable with these browsers.

Comment: Just to clarify the last sentence, you can use Javascript, such as [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to create these elements for non-HTML5 browsers like IE6, so they would be stylable.